# How to find internet disconnected using GCM Network manager?

Tags: android, gcm-network-manager

I am using GCM network manager in android to notify me if internet is available. But how to notify if internet is disconnected. What is the way . Thanks in advance. One ore thing is i dont want to use Broadcast receiver because NETWORK_CHANGED Broadcast receiver was deprecated in android Nougat 7.0